# PHP - download CSV from external URL

Tags: php, url

I hope you can help me...

I have a provider that gives me reports by accessing a URL of this format:

[https://data.xxx.com/api/export/{id}/date/csv?param=1&param=2](https://data.xxx.com/api/export/%7Bid%7D/date/csv?param=1&param=2)

that link generates the automatic download of a .CSV

What I want is to automate the downloads with a routine that builds the URLs replacing the IDs and the parameters. The resulting links work fine, but I can't get PHP to download the .CSV files and then insert them into a mySQL table.

I tried with this code without success:

```
$url = "https://data.xxx.com/api/export/id/date/csv?param=1&param=2";
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
```

And with this one with no results:

```
$url = "https://data.xxx.com/api/export/id/date/csv?param=1&param=2";
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar."
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

I found both codes by searching the forum.
Greetings

Comment: _...I can't get PHP to download the .CSV files and then insert them into a mySQL table..._ Where is the database related code?

Comment: There's nothing here to indicate what errors you might be getting with these code snippets.Add some error checking and post the results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

following should work

```
<?php
build your file name 
$param1 = "1";  
$param2 = "2";
$id = "id";

// change parameters and build the url
$file = "https://data.xxx.com/api/export/".$id."/date/csv?param=".$param1."&param=".$param2;


// Retrieve the file
$current = file_get_contents($file);

$save_name = "download1.csv";

file_put_contents($save_name, $current);
?>`
```

`However not sure whether url is correctly formatted.  just make sure it works on a browser.